# necesito me expliquen bien lo que pasa en la linea " f = d(tolower(b[1][g % strlen(b[1])])) ;"

Tags: array, c

Entiendo el código y el mismo funciona perfectamente, solo tengo una parte critica.
   Necesito que me expliquen la linea de "f = d(tolower(b[1][g % strlen(b[1])]));"
   El programa lo que hace es utilizar la encriptacion de vigenere, le das la palabra para encriptar "papa", y le das la clave con la cual encriptar "mama" y arroja el código encriptado  "baba", que solo puede ser descifrado con la palabra clave mama.

```
int f;
int g = -1;
int h;

    //get plaintext to encrypt
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");

    //iterate through each char of plaintext
    for (int j = 0, l = strlen(plaintext); j < l; j++)
    { 
        if (isalpha(plaintext[j]))
        {

            g++;
            f = d(tolower(b[1][g % strlen(b[1])]));
            h = (int) plaintext[j] + f;  
            if ((int) tolower(plaintext[j]) + f > 122)
            {
                h = h - 26;
                printf("%c", (char) h); 
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("%c", (char) h);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia contiene una buena [descripción del cifrado de Vigenere](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifrado_de_Vigen%C3%A8re) en cuyo ejemplo me voy a basar para explicar tu código.

Se trata de convertir el texto francés `"PARIS VAUT BIEN UNE MESSE"` en otro "cifrado". El método de Vigenere es muy similar al cifrado Cesar, pero mejorado. Empiezo por explicar el César que es más simple.

En el método César, a cada letra del mensaje se le suma una cantidad fija, que elige quien está cifrando. Digamos que es 15. Imagina que el alfabeto está ordenado en un círculo y a cada letra le asignas la que está 15 posiciones después. La "A" se convierte en "P", la "B" en "Q", la "K" en "Z", la "L" en "A", etc.

Si hacemos que a los espacios no se les aplique transformación, sino sólo a las letras, el mensaje quedaría entonces convertido en  `"FPHXI LPKJ QXTD KDT CTIIT"`. Para descifrar el mensaje quien lo reciba debe conocer la cantidad usada (15) y restarlo al código de cada letra.

El método de **Vigenere** es similar, sólo que en lugar de sumar la misma cantidad a cada letra, le suma una cantidad diferente a cada una. Existe una "clave" que debe ser conocida también por quien recibe el mensaje para poder descifrarlo) que es la que indica qué cantidad sumar a cada letra.

Si por ejemplo la clave es "LOUP", eso indica que la cantidad a sumar a la primera letra del mensaje ha de ser 11 (porque la "L" ocupa la posición 11 en el abecedario, si suponemos que la "A" es la posición 0). La cantidad a sumar a la segunda letra del mensaje sería 14 (pues la "O" está en posición 14), etc.

Ya que la clave solo tiene cuatro letras y en cambio el mensaje tiene más, cuando se terminan las letras de la clave se vuelve a empezar por la primera. Por tanto la quinta letra del mensaje se cifraría sumando de nuevo 11, igual que la primera letra del mensaje, etc.

## Tu código

Querías saber el significado de la línea:

```
f = d(tolower(b[1][g % strlen(b[1])]));
```

Hay que hacer algunas hipótesis para entender qué hace esto:

- `b[1]` contiene la clave de cifrado (o descifrado, ya que es la misma). En el ejemplo antes visto `b[1]` contendría la cadena `"LOUP"`
- `g` contiene un número, que nos dice qué letra del mensaje toca procesar. Por ejemplo al inicio `g=0`

Entonces lo que hace `b[1][g % strlen(b[1]))` es acceder a una letra de "LOUP", en concreto a la que toque según el valor de `g`. Veamoslo.

- `strlen(b[1])` es 4 en este ejemplo pues "LOUP" tiene cuatro letras. De modo que la expresión antes vista equivale a `b[1][g % 4]`.
- El operador `%` (llamado módulo) te da el resto de la división. En nuestro caso, el resto de dividir `g` entre 4. Este es un truco útil para asegurarte de que el resultado nunca será mayor de 4. Cuando `g=0` el resto es 0. Cuando `g=1` el resto es `1`, etc... pero cuando `g=4` el resto es 0 de nuevo, y para `g=5` vuelve a ser 1, etc.
- Así pues `b[1][g%4]` nos va dando las letras `L`, `O`, `U`, `P`, `L`, `O`, etc a medida que `g` va aumentando

En definitiva, como he dicho, nos da con qué letra hay que cifrar el elemento `g`-ésimo del mensaje.

`tolower()` pasa esa letra a minúsculas (`l`, `o`, `u`, `p`, `l`, `o`, ...) y finalmente el resultado se envía la función `d()` que no sabemos qué hace porque no has incluido su código.

Pero ya que sabemos *lo que ha de hacer*, podemos suponer que hace lo correcto, y esto es devolvernos un número que indica cuánto hay que sumar a la letra `g`-ésima del mensaje para cifrarla. En nuestro caso, si le pasamos `l` debería devolver `11`, que ya vimos que es lo que hay que sumar a la primera letra del mensaje. Este resultado se guarda en `f`.

Efectivamente puedes ver en las líneas siguientes que esa `f` se le suma a la letra correspondiente del mensaje:

```
            h = (int) plaintext[j] + f;
```

No se usa `plaintext[g]` por culpa de que nos estamos saltando los espacios a la hora de cifrar, por lo que la letra `g`-ésima del mensaje no corresponde con el caracter `j`-ésimo del array. Por ejemplo, en el mensaje "PARIS VAUT..." la sexta letra del mensaje es "V", pero sexto carácter es un espacio. `j` accede a los caracteres (y se incrementa otra vez si se encuentra un espacio) mientras que `g` cuenta las letras (y sólo se incrementa cuando se cifra una).

`h` es por tanto el código cifrado, pero en forma de número. Hay que convertirlo de nuevo en letra, lo que se hace en principio con un simple `print("%c", h)`, pero queda por ajustar el caso en que la letra cifrada "se salga del alfabeto", que es lo que se hace en el if mirando si el código resultante es mayor de 122 (código ASCII de la `"z"`), en cuyo caso se le resta 26 (número de letras en el alfabeto ASCII).

Comment: Muchas Gracias, muy útil tu respuesta. No se porque me tranque en esa linea y aun sigo sin agarrarla en el aire.

Answer (score 1):

vi el codigo y lo interpreto de la siguiente manera:

b es un vector de Strings.
Supongamos que b[1] contiene el String "papa".

Calcula el largo del string ubicado en b[1], en este caso `strlen(b[1]);` deberia retornar un 4.

Calcula el resto de la operacion entre g y el dato obtenido en el punto anterior, lo que retorna como resto 4.

Utilizando el 4 de resto, ingresa al caracter `b[1][4]`, que en nuestro caso es la letra 'a'.

El caracter ese lo pasa como parametro a la funcion `tolower()` para que en caso de que sea mayuscula, lo pase a minuscula.

El retorno de tolower() es un caracter pasado a minuscula, y ese caracter lo pasa a la funcion d() que recibe como argumento un char y retorna un int que es almacenado en f.

Espero que hayas podido entender ya que realiza varias operaciones dentro de una misma linea y es un poco confuso.

Comment: Yo no lo entiendo es muy engorroso  el algoritmo pero según dice la pregunta es como la `máquina enigma`, una máquina para codificar y decodificar mensajes, utilizada por los alemanes en la 2da guerra mundial. Tan indescifrable que de no ser que los ingleses hayan encontrado un submarino a punto de hundirse con un manual con las claves para varias semanas (por que las cambiaban todos los días) jamas la hubieran descifrado. No fue solo mérito de Turing..